# Validation localization with arrays of input in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, localization, laravel-validation, laravel-localization

for a dynamic form in which fields can be added and modified:

**in form**

```
<input name="gallery[1][title]">
<input name="gallery[1][text]">
.
.
.
<input name="gallery[n][title]">
<input name="gallery[n][text]">
```

**in controller for validation:**

```
'gallery.*.file' => 'nullable|image',
'gallery.*.title' => 'nullable|string',
```

**in localization file:**

I never know how many are going to be in the array.

```
'gallery.*.text' =>  'text of gallery 1',
'gallery.*.title' =>  'title of gallery 1',
```

how can I write it?

I want something like this in results:

> title of gallery 1
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> title of gallery n

Comment: You'll probably have to write a validator, and validate gallery with it. The validator you write can do a deep inspection

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky way to do this. Unfortunately laravel does not currently support adding general message replacers for specific tokens so here's what you could do:

In controller:

```
$replacer = function ($message, $attribute) {
    $index = array_get(explode(".",$attribute),1);
    $message = str_replace(":index",$index,$message);
    //You may need to do additional replacements here if there's more tokens
    return $message;
}
$this->getValidationFactory()->replacer("nullable", $replacer);
$this->getValidationFactory()->replacer("string", $replacer);
$this->getValidationFactory()->replacer("image", $replacer);
$v = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($v->fails()) {
   $this->throwValidationException($request, $v); //Simulate the $this->validate() behaviour
}
```

You could also add the replacers in the service provider to have them available in all routes, but unfortunately you need to register them for each rule you want them available for.

In localisation file:

```
'gallery.*.text' =>  'text of gallery :index',
'gallery.*.title' =>  'title of gallery :index',
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update in laravel 7**

*your_language/validation.php*

**es it/validation.php**

```
'attributes' => [
       'gallery.*.file' => 'Your custom message!!',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify the form and controller validation

IN Form

```
 {!! Form::open(['url' => 'actionURL']) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input name="gallery[]">

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

In Controller

```
  foreach ($request->gallery as $key => $gallery) {        
       $validator = Validator::make(array('gallery => $gallery),
                array('gallery' => 'required'));        
}
```